# How can I check if a DateTime field is blank using ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I have tried the query

`<%= f.select :ends_at_blank, [true, false], {:include_blank => "All"}, class: "show-tick"  %>`

but it creates sql error:

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
LINE 1: ...nds_at" IS NOT NULL AND "activities"."ends_at" != '')) LIMIT...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "activities"."user_id" WHERE ("users"."user_type" ILIKE '%WPD - SURV/MGR%' AND ("activities"."ends_at" IS NOT NULL AND "activities"."ends_at" != '')) LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2
```

Because it is checking for blank string as well as nil - ''

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use  _null not _blank

```
<%= f.select :ends_at_null, [true, false], {:include_blank => "All"}, class: "show-tick"  %>
```